# browse /tmp in Finder?

Tags: macos

[image]I wish to go to a specific folder, and I am trying "the menu Go -> Go to folder and enter the path of the folder " as this thread 
(https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32377/how-do-i-browse-tmp-in-finder) suggested.

However, cannot find the folder.
The folder I am  trying to enter is simply the "tmp" folder from the root folder.

I also tried  "browser (chrome, firefox), and in the URL bar file:///tmp/", but it gives a different folder compared to the folder that terminal gives.[image]

Did I missed something ? Thanks[image]

PS: from terminal the folder can be found. I only need to enter the folder from the menu for some reason (I need enter a sub-folder named "***tensorflow_logs***" which is inside "tmp" folder).

[image]

Comment: Enter `/tmp` instead of `tmp` in the "Go to folder" dialog.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: ...then please move it there

Answer (score 10):

You have 3 ways of getting your job done:

- In a terminal, type `open /tmp`
- In the Finder, "Go to folder" -> `/tmp`
- In the folder, from the root of the file system, "Go to folder" -> `tmp`.

Note the similarity between the "Go to folder" and bash when it comes to resolving absolute and relative paths. For the latter, you have to change the "working directory" before.

Comment: I use sublimetext and I am trying to navigate in the tmp dir. I don't know how to go there with SublimeText (or any other program).. I do NOT want to use finder as it does not do what I need.. any suggestions?

Comment: Hit Cmd+Shift+G from the open or save dialog, and input "/tmp" from there.

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX, and OSX is a UNIX flavor, there are *path naming conventions* which haven't changed for 40 years.

1. Terms 'Folder' and 'Directory' are interchangeable in OSX.
2. File system is like a tree,folders in the `path` hierarchy are delimited by the `/` sign  (in English: *slash*)
3. There are two types of path: *relative* and *absolute*
4. **Relative paths**, observed from current folder, start with name of the next subfolder, i.e. `tmp` (no `/` at the beginning).
5. **Asolute paths**, observed from the system root folder *always* start with `/`, i.e. (`/tmp`) in your case.

Therefore, you can reach the desired folder by typing its relative path `tmp` *only* if you are already in the root folder. From your home or desktop folder it can't be found. So it's better to use absolute path when trying to reach some of those "system owned" folders.
In OSX, some folders reserved for system functionality are invisible from Finder, in order not to confuse the casual user and keep it fool-proof.